# Mapplic with Angular 4

Tags: angular

1. In .angular-cli.json, I've included css and scripts for integration of Mapplic as

   "styles": [
       "styles.css",
       "assets/mapplic/mapplic.css",
       "assets/css/map.css"
     ],
     "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
       "assets/js/hammer.min.js",
       "assets/js/jquery.mousewheel.js",
       "assets/js/script.js",
       "assets/mapplic/mapplic.js"
     ],
2. Created a directive named mapplic.directive.ts

import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

```
// You add it here
declare var jQuery: any;

@Directive({
    selector: '[appMapplic]'
})
export class MapplicDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        jQuery(this.el.nativeElement).mapplic({
            source: '../assets/json/mall.json', */   // Using mall.json file as map data
            sidebar: true,          // Enable sidebar
            minimap: true,          // Enable minimap
            markers: false,         // Disable markers
            fillcolor: false,       // Disable default fill color
            fullscreen: true,       // Enable fullscreen 
            maxscale: 3             // Setting maxscale to 3 times bigger than the original file*/
        });
    }

}
```

3. As soon as jQuery gets initialize, it gives an error 'Zone already loaded'

Not able to find any relevant solution regarding the above.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bbj9.png)